# Laravel mix how to require a jquery library (parsely js)

Tags: javascript, laravel, ecmascript-6, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

I have a problem using parsley js (jquery plugin for from validation) in  my js file I can require it but it wouldn't work `$(...).parsley is not a function` , I use Laravel mix , I use sweet alert as well and it works properly, I tried to change the parsley.js like that :

```
module.exports = parsley;
```

instead of

```
 return parsley;
```

but I still have the same problem: `$(...).parsley is not a function` 
here is the code where I require and try to use parsley:

```
var parsley = require('../libs/parsleyjs/parsley.js');
$('[registerForm]').parsley().validate();
```

please help , Thank You

Comment: Ignore that last one. --- Just include the script on the page.

Comment: Usually a jQuery plugin should register itself with jQuery. A simple `require("parsleyjs")` should work. Make sure you're requiring the package which is installed  via your `package.json` and not a distribution package though

Comment: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html

Comment: thank You @apokryfos , that solved my problem, I installed parsley via npm and than require it from package.json

Answer (score 1):

thank You @apokryfos , that solved my problem, so the solution was to install parsley via npm and than require it like that :

`var parsley = require('parsleyjs')`

from package.json instead of

`var parsley = require('../libs/parsleyjs/parsley.js');`